# Fix two Navbars on top when scrolling

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have two Navbars that are on top of them, you could look into the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/5e3hbr8p/

But I want both of them to be stick to top even after scrolling to bottom. First Navbar and Second Navbar should both be fixed to top. I have tried multiple approaches but I think I am neglecting small things here.

This is my Navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-faded navbar-light sticky-top first-nav">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">One</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top second-nav">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Two</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How do I make both of them stick to top?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [CSS position:sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element)

Comment: When I use this, Only the second Navbar becomes sticky, while the First navbar is dissappeared.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**you can add this css on navbar that you want to sticky
You can gather more information by  w3school Visit:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky**

Comment: When I use this, Only the second Navbar becomes sticky, while the First navbar is dissappeared.

Comment: Are you added this class on your two Navbar?

Comment: Yes I have added it

Comment: No, the first Navbar gets overriden by the second

Comment: Ok. No problem.. I fixed it.. Please add your second navbar bellow code 

 .sticky_top_two {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 50px;
            z-index: 1020;
        }
And Remove ( sticky-top) from second navbar

Comment: View Demo visit: https://codepen.io/eahiya-khan/pen/eYBLyBQ

Comment: Thanks for this, but clearly I mentioned that I have two Navbars and each one is on top of other and by using the same technique the other one gets preceeded.